# Apache POI XWPFRun can't get EMF pictures

Tags: apache-poi

apache poi 3.17

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("test.docx"));
Iterator<IBodyElement> iterator = document.getBodyElementsIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    IBodyElement iBodyElement = iterator.next();
    switch (iBodyElement.getElementType()) {
        case PARAGRAPH:    
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) iBodyElement;
            for(XWPFRun run :paragraph.getRuns()){
                for(XWPFPicture picture : run.getEmbeddedPictures()){
                    System.out.println(picture.getPictureData().getFileName());
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

output

```
image3.png
image4.png
image5.png
image6.png
image7.png
image8.png
image9.png
image10.png
image11.png
image12.png
image13.png
image14.png
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD09w.png)

`image1.emf` and `image2.emf` are gone

`document.getAllPictures()` can get all the pictures, but it's XWPFPictureData

I want to take`picture.GetCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCx();`

---

`document.getAllPictures()` can get all the pictures.

I found `CTObject` and I can get the width and the height.

but how can I know which `CTObject` correspond `XWPFPictureData`?

Comment: Not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do but if you found `CTObject ` then get the XML from it. There you will find `<v:shape ...><v:imagedata ... r:id="rId[n]"/></v:shape>`. This `rId[n]` corresponds with the `XWPFPictureData` found via `XWPFDocument.getRelationById`.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks！！